# Log MySQL Query In Kohana 3

Tags: mysql, logging, kohana-3

I am using Kohana 3. I want to log the MySQL queries being executed by an application. The reason to determine the query of type INSERT,UPDATE and DELETE which are being executed in a process and store them in another MySQL table with date-time for further reference.

Can anybody tell how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to enable [profiling](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/debugging.profiling) for the database module, which will log the queries made to a file.
This will log ALL queries, not just the last one ;)

It shouldn't be too hard to parse the file, or to extend the profiling/logging/caching classes to save it to a database.

Comment: Profiling is pretty cool. Are you able to explain what the (1) behind the entries mean? Is that by any chance the number of times the entry is executed?

Comment: Yes, the `find_file` method was called 23 times in that example.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, because of the Kohana tag I approached the problem from the wrong angle. You want the MYSQL server to log the commands directly, so you get ALL of the commands, not just the last one.

See the mysql server docs on logging:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this using after() method of the controller. After execution of each controller action this after() method is executed, where I wrote logic to capture last query executed and stored in my db for further reference.